The same Tkinter window pops up again after the next button is pressed
Whenever I run the program the window will popup and I will enter the info into it like normal, when I press the next button the window exits like it's supposed to but then the same window pops up again. If i press next on this second window the window then exits for good and another window dosen't popup. How do I fix this so that the window only pops up once. I also don't want to have to put def receive_credentials in it's own class.
from ApiCredentialsWindow import ApiCredentialsWindow


def receive_credentials(get_client_id, get_client_secret):
        global CLIENT_ID
        global CLIENT_SECRET
        CLIENT_ID = get_client_id
        CLIENT_SECRET = get_client_secret
        print(CLIENT_ID)
        print(CLIENT_SECRET)


credentials_window = ApiCredentialsWindow(receive_credentials)

....
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import webbrowser


class ApiCredentialsWindow:
    def __init__(self, receive_credentials):
        self.receive_credentials = receive_credentials
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window_style = ttk.Style(self.window)
        self.window.tk.call("source", "forest-dark.tcl")
        self.window_style.theme_use("forest-dark")
        self.window.option_add("*tearOff", False)
        window_width = 375
        window_height = 320
        screen_width = self.window.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.window.winfo_screenheight()
        window_position_x = (screen_width // 2) - (window_width // 2)
        window_position_y = (screen_height // 2) - (window_height // 2)
        self.window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{window_position_x}+{window_position_y}")
       

        client_id_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Client ID", font=("Segoe UI", 11),      background=dark_gray_color)
        client_id_label.pack(pady=(10, 0))
        self.client_id_entry = ttk.Entry(self.window, width=30)
        self.client_id_entry.pack(pady=(0, 10))

        client_secret_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Client secret:", font=("Segoe UI", 11), background=dark_gray_color)
        client_secret_label.pack(pady=(10, 0))
        self.client_secret_entry = ttk.Entry(self.window, width=30)
        self.client_secret_entry.pack(pady=(0, 10))

        next_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text="Next", style="Accent.TButton", command=self.get_credentials)
        next_button.pack(pady=(15, 0))

        self.window.mainloop()


    def get_credentials(self):
        get_client_id = self.client_id_entry.get()
        get_client_secret = self.client_secret_entry.get()
        self.receive_credentials(get_client_id, get_client_secret)
        self.window.destroy()
```


It is better to provide a [mre].

Please clarify exactly how this code is split up among files.  It looks like it's supposed to be two files, with import tkinter as tk as the first line of the second file - but I cannot reproduce the problem with that setup, so I suspect you've done something different.

Note that calling mainloop() inside __init__() is really a bad design and should be avoided.

__init__() will be executed when you want to create an instance of that class, but since mainloop() is a blocking function, that means the instance will be created after mainloop() returns (i.e. after closing the window).  In such design, it behaves just like a normal function.

I divided your code into two files, Chass43.py and  ApiCredentialsWindow.py. When I run Chass43.py I get two Entry widgets and a Button. Everything works!? I don't see any problem.

Your code is working. But I cannot get second window. line 44, in get_credentials
 self.receive_credentials(get_client_id, get_client_secret)
TypeError: ApiCredentialsWindow.get_credentials() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given


Here is screenshot... https://ibb.co/3fJ5Yxy

So I just figured it out. I'm using flask and for some reason when using app.run(debug=True) instead of app.run(debug=False) this issue occurs. If I set it to false, the window pops up once, but if I set it to True the window pops up twice. If anyone knows why this occurs, please let me know.

Well, app.run(debug=True) turns debug mode on...
